# how to use puppeteer-sharp touchStart and touchEnd and touch move

Tags: c#, puppeteer, puppeteer-sharp

The Touchscreen in puppeteer-sharp API just gives one method: TapAsync. but I need drag(touchStart and touchEnd and touch move). How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

PuppeteerSharp doesn't have those APIs (because Pupppeteer doesn't have them). But, you could try sending those messages to the browser in the same way `TapAsync` does.

This is the `TapAsync` code:

```
// Touches appear to be lost during the first frame after navigation.
// This waits a frame before sending the tap.
// @see https://crbug.com/613219
await _client.SendAsync("Runtime.evaluate", new RuntimeEvaluateRequest
{
    Expression = "new Promise(x => requestAnimationFrame(() => requestAnimationFrame(x)))",
    AwaitPromise = true
}).ConfigureAwait(false);

var touchPoints = new[] { new TouchPoint { X = Math.Round(x), Y = Math.Round(y) } };
await _client.SendAsync("Input.dispatchTouchEvent", new InputDispatchTouchEventRequest
{
    Type = "touchStart",
    TouchPoints = touchPoints,
    Modifiers = _keyboard.Modifiers
}).ConfigureAwait(false);

await _client.SendAsync("Input.dispatchTouchEvent", new InputDispatchTouchEventRequest
{
    Type = "touchEnd",
    TouchPoints = Array.Empty<TouchPoint>(),
    Modifiers = _keyboard.Modifiers
}).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Page has a public property [Client](https://github.com/hardkoded/puppeteer-sharp/blob/master/lib/PuppeteerSharp/Page.cs#L103). You can use that Client to perform these calls.

As you can check [here](https://vanilla.aslushnikov.com/?Input.dispatchTouchEvent), Type supports: touchStart, touchEnd, touchMove and  touchCancel.

Comment: Thansks. I has another question, how to implement function from the link:https://medium.com/@jsoverson/using-chrome-devtools-protocol-with-puppeteer-737a1300bac0 . I need to Intercepte the link ,but the link over then start a javascript Navigation immediately.  this is a chrome bug